# Run a persistent process via ssh

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

I'm trying to start a test server via ssh but it always dies once i disconnect from ssh.

Is there a way to start a process (run the server) so it doesn't die upon the end of my ssh session?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As an alternative to [**`nohup`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup), you could run your remote application inside a terminal multiplexor, such as [GNU **`screen`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [**`tmux`**](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Using these tools makes it easy to reconnect to a session from another host, which means that you can kick a long build or download off before you leave work and check on its status when you get home. For instance. I find this particularly useful when doing development work on servers that are very remote (in a different country) with unreliable connectivity between me and them, if the connection drops, I can simply reconnect and carry on without losing any state.

Comment: Example: Using ssh and screen To Create Persistent Terminal Sessions Accessible From Almost Anywhere http://bit.ly/1ewxKKv

Answer (score 11):

If you're SSHing to a Linux distro that has systemd, you can use `systemd-run` to launch a process in the background (in systemd's terms, "a transient service"). For example, assuming you want to ping something in the background:

```
systemd-run --unit=pinger ping 10.8.178.3
```

The benefit you'll get with systemd over just running a process with `nohup` is that systemd will track the process and its children, keep logs, remember the exit code and allow you to cleanly kill the process and all its children. Examples:

See the status and the last lines of output:

```
systemctl status pinger
```

Stream the output:

```
journalctl -xfu pinger
```

Kill:

```
systemctl kill pinger
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes; you can use [the `nohup` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) to swallow the HUP ("hangup") signal that is sent to your program when you hang up your SSH session.

Alternatively, if you're writing the server yourself, you can code it to [register a handler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#Handling_signals) for the HUP signal, and swallow it inside the program (rather than using an external `nohup` program that does the same).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other replies, you could start your test server thru [batch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/batch) (or `at`) but as [Brian answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237602/841108) you should call `daemon`

And you could pass the `-f` option to [ssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day for the `-f` option to ssh.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `nohup`, `screen`, et al. you could revise your server to invoke `daemon` to detach it from the terminal.  This is the idiomatic way to write services for linux.

See also [`daemon(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html).