# start daemon on remote server via Jenkins SSH shell script exits mysteriously

Tags: shell, ssh, jenkins, daemon

I have a build job on jenkins that is building my project and after it is done, it opens an ssh shell script on a remote server and transfers files and then stop and starts a daemon.

When I stop and start the daemon from the command line on a RHEL server, it executes just fine.  When the job executes in jenkins, there are no errors.

The daemon stops fine and it starts fine.  But shortly after starting, the daemon dies suddenly.

```
sudo service daemonName stop
# transfer files.
sudo service daemonName start
```

I'm sure that the problem isn't pathing

Does anyone know what could be special about the way Jenkins is executing the ssh shell script that would cause the daemon start to not fully complete?

Comment: Have you checked the logs? What errors do you read in there?

Comment: the jenkins logs? or the console logs? or the logs of the daemon?

the console logs show that everything was successful.
The logs of the daemon don't show any problems
The jenkins log I doubt will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe the daemon is not properly daemonized, have you tried adding a `sleep 10000` to the shell script in Jenkins to see whether it runs longer when the invoking shell isn't closed? Have you tried comparing `env` output in Jenkins and the shell? If it's a homegrown daemon, it might be affected by things like locale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem:
When executing a build through jenkins, the command to start the daemon process was clearly successfully executing, yet after the build job was done, the daemon would suddenly quit.

The solution:
I thought for this whole time that it was jenkins killing the daemon.  So I tried many different incarnations and permutations of disabling the ProcessTree module that goes through and cleans up zombie child processes. I tried fooling it by resetting the BUILD_ID environment variable.  Nothing worked.

Thanks to this thread I found out that that solution only works for child processes executed on the BUILD machine.  I.E.  not applicable to my problem.

More searching led me here: [Run a persistent process via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237385/run-a-persistent-process-via-ssh)

The solution? Nohup.

So now the build successfully restarts the daemon by executing the following:
sudo nohup service daemonname start

Comment: nohup saved me too... but strangely it didn't work when I appended '&' at the end of the line. I had to omit '&' for the remote script invocation to work.

Answer (score 7):

Jenkins watches for processes spawned by the job and kill them to avoid zombie processes.
See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

The workaround is to override the `BUILD_ID` environment variable:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
```

Comment: Okay, I've tried this in many different incarnations but it doesn't seem to work.  I've tried adding the flag to turn off the process tree killer, I've tried changing the build id in the ssh script i'm executing 


BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
sudo service servicename start

is in a "execute shell script on remote host over ssh"
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: ok, looks like I misread you question. The process three killer only runs on the jenkins node (or the connected slaves) but not on the remote machine, so the source of you problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: I'm glad you did, your answer just resolved a day long headache of mine. Thanks =)