# Listener starting from terminal but not from Jenkins

Tags: perl, jenkins, listener

I have written a perl script to start the listener on a database. The perl script runs fine when run from the terminal,it starts the listener and even when I logout of the machine and log back in, the listener is up and running(as it should be).

But I am facing a problem when I try to do the same through Jenkins. I have added that VM as a slave on Jenkins and am running that same script from the Jenkins `Execute Shell` option. The console output from Jenkins shows that the listener has been started, and `ps -ef | grep tnsl` shows the listener is up, but only as long as the script from Jenkins is running. As soon as the Jenkins build completes , `ps -ef | grep tnsl` shows no results.

I have been trying to debug this for sometime. Can anyone throw some light here ? I understand the question may sound vague when first read, but I am happy to provide any info anyone deems necessary.

Comment: You could daemonize it `daemonize -E BUILD_ID=dontKillMe /path/to/script`. See [Spawning processes from build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16677609) to a similar question, the [Jenkins ProcessTreeKiller](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller) watches for spawned processes and eliminates them to avoid zombies.

To disable this behavior for a particular job, change the environment variable BUILD_ID which ProcessTreeKiller looks for. For example:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe  /my/database/listener/script.pl
```

Alternatively, the feature can be can be disabled for all jobs when Jenkins is launched:

```
java -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true -jar jenkins.war
```