# Run a persistent process via ssh in Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, persistence, conemu

Picking up on the accepted answer in this post,
[Run a persistent process via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237385/run-a-persistent-process-via-ssh)

I'd like to know if I could achieve the same with an equivalent Windows terminal multiplexor, such as ConEmu, and how I'd go about to do that.

Comment: It likely depends on your specific sshd implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it from the server side, using dtach (read here http://www.kossboss.com/linux---screen-detach-some-cool-stuff).

I was trying to figure this out by myself and was a bit confused. I'm not sure if tmux provides persistency by itself. but

Anyways I was able to connect from Windows with a SSH session (using Putty) and from there install and run dtach on the remote system. I was running ConEmu on top of Putty for a nicer, multiplex interface (http://www.thecrumb.com/2013/03/04/configuring-conemu-and-putty/).