# python subprocess run a remote process in background and immediately close the connection

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

The task is to use python to run a remote process in background and immediately close the ssh session.

I have a remote script name 'start' under server:PATH/, the start script does nothing but lunch a long-live background program. 'start' script which has one line:

```
nohup PATH/Xprogram &
```

When I use python subprocess module to call my remote 'start' script, it does start OK. But the issue is: it seems the SSH connection is persist, meaning I am getting stdout from the remote Xprogram (since it is a long live program which has output to stdout). Does this indicating ssh connection is still there ?

All I need is call the start script without blocking and forget about it (leave the long-live program running, close ssh, release resources).

my python function call looks like this:

```
ret = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "xxx@servername", "PATH/start"])
```

if I use `ret.terminate()` after the command, it then will kill the long-live program too.
I have also tried spur module. basically the same thing.

=====update====

@Dunes' answer solves the problem. Based on his answer, I did more digging and found [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30400/execute-remote-commands-completely-detaching-from-the-ssh-connection) very helpful. 
My understanding of this is: basically, if any file descriptor is still held by your process (e.g. stdout held by my XProgram), then SSH session won't exit. However redirect stdout/stderr to NULL effectively close those file descriptor and let SSH session exit normally.

**solution**

```
ret = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "xxx@servername", "PATH/start >dev/null 2>&1"])
```

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592219/launch-a-totally-independent-process-from-python relevant?  Or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661527/how-to-spawn-detached-background-process-on-linux-in-either-bash-or-python ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a persistent process via ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237385/run-a-persistent-process-via-ssh)

Comment: Seems to be an issue more to do with with ssh than python. Passing the `-f` option to ssh will achieve what you want.

Comment: i have tried -f and it does not seem to work either. same result with or w/o -f .  ret = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "-f", "xxx@servername", "PATH/start"])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing about a bit I found that `nohup` doesn't seem to be properly disconnecting the child process from the parent ssh session (as it should be). This means you have to manually close stdout or point it at a file, e.g.

Using bash:

```
ssh user@host "nohup PATH/XProgram >&- &"
```

Shell agnostic (as far as I know):

```
ssh user@host "nohup PATH/XProgram >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

In python:

```
from shlex import split
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen(split('ssh user@host "nohup PATH/XProgram >&- &"'))
p.communicate() # returns (None, None)
```

Comment: thanks, man. ">/dev/null 2>&1 &" works like a charm.  But why redirection can causing nohup detach from SSH and let ssh exit normally ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "xxx@servername", "nohup PATH/start & disown"])
```

For me,

```
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "xxx@servername", "nohup sleep 1000 & disown"])
```

lets my script exit immediately while leaving `sleep` running on the server awhile.

When your script dies, an `ssh` process is left on your system, but `kill`ing it doesn't kill the remote process.